# Change color of a row on onclick of that particular row

Tags: javascript, row

I am creating a html table dynamically as follows:

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable"); 
            var rowcount = document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length;      
            var row = table.insertRow(rowcount);            
            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
            var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
            var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

            cell1.innerHTML = rowcount;
            cell2.innerHTML = "a";
            cell3.innerHTML = "b";
            cell4.innerHTML = "c";
            cell5.innerHTML = document.getElementById("select_product_name").value;
```

The last column in a row ie, `cell5` which contains the `id`

**I want a function in such a way that onclick of row in the table should get the id i.e., the value of `cell5` and that full row should change color to red.**

> Note: use only Javascript not jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var table = document.getElementById("mytable"); 
var rowcount = document.getElementById("mytable").rows.length;      

var row = table.insertRow(rowcount);            
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
var cell5 = row.insertCell(4);

cell1.innerHTML = rowcount;
cell2.innerHTML = "a";
cell3.innerHTML = "b";
cell4.innerHTML = "c";

var id = document.getElementById("select_product_name").value;
cell5.innerHTML = id;

row.onclick = function() {
    // Add a css class to the row
    row.className += ' red';

    // Alert the id
    alert(id);
};
```

Comment: it is working partially. How can change color? `row.className += ' red';` not working

Comment: I got it buddy . so u mean red is a class!!

Comment: Yes, `red` is a CSS class. You just have to write some CSS to change the row color.

Comment: Ok buddy I got it. Thanks a lot